# Ad tag and trying to use append / appendTo instead of document.write - not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I did alot of searching and couldn't locate an answer. This is the code

```
<div id="uniquediv"></div>
     <script language="JavaScript">
            (function($){
               var srcitem = 'http://someURL_to_an_AD_tag';
                   $('<script/>', {
                      type:    'text/javascript',
                      src:     srcitem
                   }).appendTo("#uniquediv");
            })(jQuery);
     </script>
```

No matter what I do (tried many diff things), the js code falls outside the "uniqueid" div. I need it IN the div because the div has padding and I need to retain that since the js I am including is an ad and I need to have padding around it.

Comment: sorry - i don't quite get it yet. the script isn't actually displayed on the website, so why bother where it is output in the source code?

Comment: why not use document.write? that will cause the script to be loaded right at that moment rather than some time later.

Comment: I 'was' using document.write but I thought that was frowned upon. The script is displaying and showing the ad, but it is just "outside" of the div. Since I appendTo, I figured it would be inserted inside the div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I completely retract my previous answer).

When you do `$("<script>")` in jQuery, the script is downloaded and executed immediately.  The .appendTo is likely not having any effect in that case, especially if the ad is doing document.write.

document.write is probably the way to go in this case.  I don't think there is any downside really.  If your ad src is static, you may even want to skip javascript entirely and just do a  tag in your div.

Comment: thanks - already tried that. no go. This is why I am posting, just really odd that appendTo won't actually work in this case.

Comment: yeah, after some additional testing - it seems to be an issue with "when things load" and as such, I can't achieve the effect I want unless I start making things too convoluted. I am just gonna go with the doc write as I previously had it. I was just trying to refactor the code. Thanks.